# Upgrade from 22.04.1 to 22.04.3?

Tags: upgrade

dumb question but here goes. I downloaded the iso over Ubuntu's official page a month ago, installed it and have been using it since with regular updates but I see now (`uname -a`) that my Ubuntu version is 22.04.1.

> ```
> linux gtomas-Swift-SF314-41 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```

I see now that the version 22.04.3 is on the website. How do I update to 22.04.3. Software updater does not offer that upgrade without me changing the updates to "all new versions".

Should I even do it if it risks stability? What are the pros and cons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a terminal, run

```
lsb_release -a
```

and see what output you get.
Normal updates/upgrades will get you to the latest 22.04.

Comment: Oh, I see.
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy