# 22.04.1 to 22.04.3 or kernel upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, 22.04

I installed initially 22.04.1 (in 2022), and did all updates.

But, the kernel is still 5.15.0-94 while 22.04.3 comes with kernel 6.2...

And `lsb_release -a` says

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493064/upgrade-from-22-04-1-to-22-04-3) seem to address a similar issue, but their kernel is 6.2!

Did I miss a step to get the new kernel(s)?

What can I do to keep 22.04 and have the new kernel 6.2 (safely)?

*edit*

```
[root@here ~/]# dpkg --get-selections | grep '^linux' | grep -vw deinstall

linux-base                  install
linux-firmware                  install
linux-generic                   install
linux-headers-5.15.0-92             install
linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic         install
linux-headers-5.15.0-94             install
linux-headers-5.15.0-94-generic         install
linux-headers-generic               install
linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic           install
linux-image-5.15.0-94-generic           install
linux-image-generic             install
linux-libc-dev:amd64                install
linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic         install
linux-modules-5.15.0-94-generic         install
linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic       install
linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-94-generic       install
linux-sound-base                install
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `dpkg --get-selections | grep '^linux'`. Have you tried switching to `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04`?

Comment: @DanielT edited. I didn't install hwe but that could be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` should work. Then after rebooting and verifying, you can remove `linux-generic` if you want

Comment: Thanls - I did hwe on another version a few years ago and I rolled back, don't recall why.  Is there a risk to go hwe?

Comment: I've been using 6.5 (and non-LTS) and it has worked fine for me. Remember that it GRUB will let you chose the previous kernel, so you can roll back at any time to reinstall non-HWE if there is a problem

Comment: Thanks, using systemd-boot instead of grub, and it's great ;-)

Comment: Your install media dictates the default kernel stack; 22.04.3 media exists that will install with the GA kernel stack (ie. 5.15) as well as HWE (6.2 though as 22.04.4 updates are rolling out it will upgrade to 6.5 post-install quickly).   Server & Desktop have different defaults; and with *flavor* ISOs the install will be GA or HWE depending on media (just as with all LTS releases from 12.04 LTS so this isn't new)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, the way to get newer kernels on a LTS older version is to install the HWE version.

For 22.04, the command is

```
apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

Comment: All of the point releases of 22.04 install the hwe packages by default (even the 22.04.1, which until just recently, I thought didn't).